# Why it is not required for ViewController class to conform to the NSObject Protocol while necessary for other classes

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ColorizerTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
   ... Some protocol to colorize the text
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
   ... In ViewController UITextFieldDelegate is only used for character count.
}
```

If I remove the NSObject I get error that the Type 'ColorizerTextFieldDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
But I see it is not necessary for the ViewController class to conform to NSObject protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, [as you can see under "inherits from" in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller), `UIViewController` inherits from `UIResponder`, which in turn inherits from `NSObject`.

To clarify on protocols vs classes: `NSObjectProtocol` and `UITextFieldDelegate` are both protocols. `UITextFieldDelegate` inherits from `NSObjectProtocol` - for protocols, this means that **in order to conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`, you also need to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`**. Since `UIViewController` already conforms to `NSObjectProtocol` because of the above paragraph, all it needs to do is conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`. Your `ColorizerTextFieldDelegate` class, on the other hand, does not get that for free, so that's why you need to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: UITextFieldDelegate Inherits From NSObjectProtocol and the NSObjectProtocol is Adopted By NSObject that confuses me a little, can you please simply that for me?

Comment: `UIViewController`, `UIResponder`, `UITextField` and `NSObject` are all classes. So they can inherit from other classes (if this is new to you I'd do some Googling on "subclassing"). `UITextFieldDelegate` and `NSObjectProtocol` are protocols, not classes. **Classes need to conform to protocols by implementing the protocol's requirements**. The fact that `UITextFieldDelegate` inherits from `NSObjectProtocol` means that, for a class to _conform_ to `UITextFieldDelegate`, it also needs to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: @Connor you should add your comment to your answer.